# Error in Build qtdeclarative module

Tags: git, qt, cross-compiling

I cross compile QT 5.6 from [this link](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS) 
for Raspberry pi on Ubuntu 14.04
I want to get and make the module with this command that said in the guide:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtdeclarative.git -b 5.6

cd qtdeclarative

~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake -r

make

make install
```

and when make it I get these error :

```
items/qquicktextcontrol.cpp:1289:14: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if QT_CONFIG(im)
              ^
items/qquicktextcontrol.cpp:1572:14: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if QT_CONFIG(clipboard)
              ^
items/qquicktextcontrol.cpp:1622:14: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if QT_CONFIG(texthtmlparser)
              ^
items/qquicktextcontrol.cpp:1712:14: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if QT_CONFIG(im)
              ^
items/qquicktextcontrol.cpp:1774:14: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if QT_CONFIG(texthtmlparser)
              ^
items/qquicktextcontrol.cpp:1801:14: error: missing binary operator before token "("....
```

from qquicktextcontrol class ,is it need a library?,qinputcontorl library is not recognize by it and I add complete address in header file                                                               I change  `<QtGui/private/qinputcontrol_p.h>`
to **`</home/ubuntu/qtbase/include/QtGui/5.6.0/QtGui/private/qinputcontrol_p.h>`**                                                                  so it can find the library ,What new library is this class need?or need to define complete address?Also I add `#include </home/ubuntu/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h>` to headers of class and still I get errors

what should I do?

Comment: I get the module from https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.6/5.6.0/submodules/
instead of http://code.qt.io/qt/qtdeclarative.git
and then I do
 cd <qt-module>

~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake -r
make
make install

and it is work for me  with no error